# how to stop duplicate values from being written to text file using php

Tags: php, duplicates, preg-split

i have a script that keeps reloading every 2 seconds, i made a code to create a txt file for each user IP and write the user name `$name` inside it. my problem is that everytime my script reloads it will write the `$name` of the specific IP again with every reload.
the code is

```
 $ip_file = "ips/".$ip.".txt";

    $logip = fopen($ip_file,"a", 1);

    $name = $name."\n";

    fwrite($logip, $name);  

    fclose($logip);

    return;
```

i need some way to verify if the name is already in the `$ip_file` and if it's there then not to write it again.

the idea behind this is to check if the same IP is used by more than one `$name` and then create a function to check all the `$ip_file` files for more than 1 `$name` and if so ban the violating `$ip`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ip_file = "ips/".$ip.".txt";
$names = file_get_contents($ip_file); //read names into string
if(false === strpos($names,$name)) { //write name if it's not there already
    file_put_contents($ip_file,"$name\n",FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: +1 that's better than my answer, I couldn't understand the main idea

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked exactly the way i want it to :)
i think i will now need a way using preg_split to check if file has more than one name to perform a function

Comment: how can i add a code to check if more than 1 `$name` is in `$ip_file` to execute another command ?
thanks in advance

Comment: @GuestofHonor `if(count(file($ip_file)) > 1)`

Comment: @FuzzyTree, that command didn't work, as it banned all my users :)
command counted `$ip_file` and not the `$name` inside the file :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
<?php
$ip_file = "ips/".$ip.".txt";
$name = $name."\n";

if (file_exists($ip_file)) {

    $valueInFile = file_get_contents($ip_file, true);

    if ($valueInFile == $name) {
       //Do something
    }
} else {
    $logip = fopen($ip_file,"a", 1);
    fwrite($logip, $name);  
    fclose($logip);
}
return;
?>
```

From:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: This answer is not related to duplicate values.

Comment: i'm already writing that filename.txt so i know it exists, i need to verify the data inside it

Comment: oh sorry, then maybe the "a" parameter? Is not from append?